# Calculate triangle areas - R

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate triangle area of pair of running points (X1, Y1,…. Xn, Yn) with a fix point (Cx,Cy) but without success. Can someone tell  me please what is the problem so I can try to solve it?

Script:

```
library(ggplot2)

nElem <- 100
xData <- as.data.frame(seq(1,nElem,5))
yData <- as.data.frame(seq(5,nElem,5))
xyDATA<- cbind(xData,yData)
colnames(xyDATA) <- c("xCoord","yCoord")

Cx <- 10
Cy <- 1

ggplot(xyDATA) + geom_point(aes(x = xCoord, y = yCoord)) + geom_point(aes(x = Cx, y = Cy),colour="red",size=4)

for(i in 1:19) 
{
  Ax <- xyDATA[i,1]
  Ay <- xyDATA[i,2]
  Bx <- xyDATA[i+1,1]
  By <- xyDATA[i+1,2]


  s <-  abs(0.5*((Ax*(By-Cy))+(Bx*(Cy-Ay))+(Cx*(Ay-By))))
  # print(Ax)
  # print(Ay)
  # print(Bx)
  # print(By)
  print(s)
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. What's wrong with the output you get?

Comment: Waats not working?

Comment: The  calculated area are all the same (s=32.5). It can not be that x1,y1;x2,y2; Cx,Cy triangle will be with the same area as x19,y19;x20,y20; Cx,Cy.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see the point graph drawn then you should modify `ggplot` line like:

```
    p <- ggplot(xyDATA) + geom_point(aes(x = xCoord, y = yCoord)) +
 geom_point(aes(x = Cx, y = Cy),colour="red",size=4)

    print(p)
```

The `print()` method for the graph object produces the actual display.

Now the image is shown as:
[image]